# LuaD class table copying

Tags: lua, d, embedding

Consider this in D programming language:

```
import luad.all

class C1
{
auto l1 = new LuaState;
l1["somebool"] = true;

this()
~this()
}

class C2
{

C1 cc = new C1;
auto l2 = new LuaState;
// here I want to inject l1["somebool"] to l2
}

void main() { C2 cx = new C2; }
```

As a solution, it is possible that I make a local variable

```
bool var = cc.l1["somebool"]
```

and then insert it in l2 - but this does not seem to be the best solution.

Is there any way to copy one lua stack defined inside a class to another stack in another class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `LuaD` or `Lua`, but you can extract globals into a struct as shown in the last example on this [page](http://jakobovrum.github.io/LuaD/). And then you can set the values from the struct into `l2` state.

```
// warning: untested

struct State
{
  bool somebool;
}

State state;
l1.globals.toStruct!State(state);

foreach (member; __traits(allMembers, State))
{
    l2.globals.set(member, __traits(getMember, state, member));
}
```

Comment: I apologize for this : But I understand that in your method, I do not have to define the types for each variable in the D side, but in case of a sturct, I have to define what I am expecting out of the l1.globals?

Comment: By the way, it does not work. Error message is :
cannot infer type for k and
cannot infer type for v

Comment: You are right, my previous code didn't work. I've went with the struct method. And yes, in this case, you will need to define what you're expecting.